# What is the proper way to Windows workstation agnostically setup a broadcast client?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, winsock, broadcast

I have been trying to make a broadcast client for simple LAN communication, and I have made a fairly simple client and server with a basic data serialization interface. I've been having problems with figuring out how to get the "directed broadcast" address for any workstation I'm using so I can set up the the chat. I'm new to networking, so I don't have a lot of experience in this area. I tried looking up examples, but most of the ones I found wasn't what I wanted. Everything works on the loopback address, broadcasting is my only problem area currently.

I learned the basic idea from [Beej's tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#broadcast) which gives a short explanation on exactly what broadcast packets are and some of the pitfalls like firewall, network load, and perhaps a few less obvious ones. Then I enhanced this knowledge with a more winsock oriented site, the [Winsock's Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html), which puts it with more relevancy for Windows specific programs like mine.

Although I understood the idea behind broadcasting, I wasn't able to modify the program in such a way that it would be workstation agnostic and broadcast packets from the client to the server. From several of the SO questions I've read and the Winsock FAQ aforementioned, I found out also that the idea of "getting the local IP address" wasn't exactly black and white. As the user may have several different means of network or have different addresses that you can use. This is the main issue that baffled me in how to handle properly.

My current function that I use to wrap this behavior is this :

```
extern void WINAPI setup_connection( connection_data * data )
{
    char host_name[128] = { 0 };

    struct in_addr host_address;
    struct in_addr broadcast_address;

    if ( gethostname( &host_name[0], sizeof( host_name ) ) == HOST_NOT_FOUND )
    {
        winsock_error( "Getting host name", WSAGetLastError( ), FALSE );
        destroy_winsock_data( data );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    if ( !( data->host_info = gethostbyname( &host_name[0] ) ) )
    {
        winsock_error( "Getting host by name", WSAGetLastError( ), FALSE );
        destroy_winsock_data( data );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    host_address = *( ( struct in_addr * )data->host_info->h_addr );
    broadcast_address.S_un.S_addr = ( host_address.S_un.S_addr & NETMASK ) | ( ~( NETMASK ) );

    data->broadcast_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    data->broadcast_address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    data->broadcast_address.sin_addr = broadcast_address;

    return;
}
```

The hostname seemed to be correct, but the gethostbyname returned a trash value apparently. If I try to retrieve the IP address returned, it says that the "Address is invalid". The send calls don't error for some reason though, but the packets are never sent to my understanding.

If you're wondering, I set the socket to broadcast like this :

```
extern int WINAPI set_socket_to_broadcast( int socket, BOOL setting )
{
   char broadcast = ( setting ? '1' : '0' );

   if ( setsockopt( socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof( char ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR )
   {
       winsock_error( "Setting Broadcast", WSAGetLastError( ), FALSE );
       return -1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Then if you're wondering what my connection_data structure is, I declare it like this :

```
typedef struct connection_data
{
    struct sockaddr_in broadcast_address;
    struct hostent * host_info;

    int socket;
} connection_data;
```

If you need any more details, I will be able to check and post again by tomorrow probably.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that's wrong here is that the netmask isn't a constant, it's a property of the interface which you can retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `gethostname()` and `gethostbyname()` to retrieve the local IP addresses.  It does not always work, and can even report false information.  Not only that, but it does not give you access to subnet information, which you need to calculate broadcast IP addresses.  Each IP adapter that is connected to a network has its own IP and Subnet, so you have to use those values that are associated with the adapter that is actually sending the broadcast.  Use platform-specific APIs instead to enumerate local IP adapters.  On Windows, use [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetAdapterAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  On *Nix-based platforms, use [`getifaddrs()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).  Any of these will give you IP and Subnet information (`getifaddrs()` even gives you the actual broadcast IP).